# Windows App Store - Stretched icon

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I'm having a small problem with the windows store.
I have uploaded all the required graphics in the submission, and the app has all of the required graphics (including box and wide tile images).

In the store however, the app entry is using a wide image. The problem is that the wide image it's using is actually a box image , that's stretched.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: I got the same problem. In the first submission I only uploaded one icon. Then I added the others but the streched grapic doesn't change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in touch with Microsoft support regarding this bug. It was fixed just two days ago.

You just **need to upload new package/version of your Windows 8.1 app** now and the proper icons will be used for Windows 8.1 Store!

Answer (score 7):

I contacted Microsoft support because I had the same problem with the new update of my app, but the issue didn't occur before.

This is a part of the conversation:

**Microsoft**
We are currently aware of this issue and working to resolve it.
**Me**:
Ok, so this is an issue with the windows store??
**Microsoft**:
Yes it is.
**Me**:
thank you for your help :) I hope it won't affect the number of downloads for my app
**Microsoft**:
We are working to resolve this as soon as possible.  I will update you via email once I have more information.

In summary, it's a Microsoft problem and they're working to fix it

Comment: Well, they are taking their sweet time with this. Eh well, given the state of their dashboard, i've come to expect such slow problem solving times.

Comment: Yea, I also got the following answer: I do not have an ETA on when this might be fixed but as soon I have an update I will let you know.

Comment: My downloads rate has dropped by half since this problem... At least windows 10 is coming in a few days and there's no problem on its store.

Comment: I was hit with the same issue.  Did you find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: Microsoft contacted me 2 days ago to tell me that they're still working on the issue.

At least windows 10 is released, so people will move to the new store (where the icon is working)

Comment: It's August 6th, we've just published two new apps for Windows 8.1 and they are still shown with ugly stretched logo. I hope the fix comes really soon.

Comment: I can't believe this is taking so long

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Contacted MS support and still no ETA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a part of an email I received today:
We have received an update on this issue, and "a partial fix has been implemented. Any new submissions and updates should no longer encounter the issue, and we are working diligantly to have the existing applications fixed soon. If you would like, you are welcome to submit an update on any affected applications in an effort to resolve this sooner; however, the remainder of this fix should be rolled out soon."

It's finally resolved :)

Comment: They say it's resolved, but my icon is still stretched...
I'll wait anoter day

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED!!!!
I noticed that most icons are solved in the store, but some remained. I just published a new Submission, so I think it's related

Comment: I resubmitted the app and the problem was solved, but they are still sending me updates that they are working to fix my issue ... lol.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, they actually replied , notifying me that they have found the cause and are deploying a fix. They must have the worst debugging teams in the history of the universe ...