# Windows Store Logo Streteched

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, graphical-logo

I have published a Windows 8.1 to Store With all these logo

```
BadgeLogo.scale-100.png     Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png
Logo.scale-100.png          Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png
SmallLogo.scale-100.png     StoreLogo.scale-100.png
SplashScreen.scale-100.png  Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png
```

But when I published to the store, it is stretched like this:

[image]
I measured this stretched tiled logo (in the screenshot), the dimensions are 310x150 , then I double checked the list the 310x150 wide logo is there. This is supposed to be very simple, but I cannot get it right after several submission to the store. Can the experts out there give me any hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your fault.

There is a thread, explaining this issue: [Windows App Store - Stretched icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470392/windows-app-store-stretched-icon)
In summary, it's a Microsoft problem and they're working to fix it.

Comment: Also mentioned here on MSDN - http://bit.ly/1IMxsBv - Its just so slack microsoft